# Create a new AD user by copying all attributes of an existing AD user

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

We have a requirement to create new AD users through perl using NET::LDAPS.
The new user needs to be a copy of an existing user.
On the Active Directory GUI (dsa.msc), we would simply select the existing user and create a copy with new username and details. This copies all attributes including groups the user is a member of.

Is there similar code using LDAP that would copy all attributes of an existing user into a new user(including groups).
Alternatively, do we need to first create the AD user and then add the user to existing groups. In this case, how do we find out the groups that the existing user is a member of?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to update the directory manually.  Keep in mind that perl-ldap is a library for the protocol LDAP and not for Active Directory which is just one application for LDAP.

And, by the way, it's Net::LDAPS, not Net::LDAP.  The latter will only work on case-insensitive file systems.